# Macro printing the value in register

Tags: assembly

## I'm writing macro that will print the given value.

Here is macro:

```
macro print number
    pusha
    mov word ptr ax,number

    xor dx,dx        ;repetitions
    analyse:         ;pushes the digits into stack
        mov cx,16    ;divisor
        div cx                 ;divide number by 16
        movsx  cx,[al]    ;remainder into the stack   
        push cx  
        movsx ax,[ah]    ;prepare quotient for next loop

        inc dx
        cmp ax,0             ;break condition
        jne analyse

    begin1:                 ;print character stored in the stack
        pop dx              ;pop to DL
        cmp dl,10d          ;is DL digit or char
        jb digit
        ja char             ;convert to ASCII
            digit:
                add dl,87d
            char:
                add dl,'0'
        mov ah,2           ;print character converted to ASCII 
        int 21h
    loop begin1

    popa
endm print
```

My try to use it:

```
    mov ax,9
    print ax
```

I have no idea how to make it work.

I'm not sure the instruction movsx ax,ah

Comment: The macro you've defined is called `print`, not `printnum`…

Comment: I have corrected it.

Comment: What assembler do you use?

Comment: Masm. here is working version of this macro:

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42993405/macro-printing-a-value-stored-in-a-byte-assembly-masm